# How to configure Yii2 with AdminLTE theme

Tags: php, yii2

I'm new to Yii2 Framework and just configured Yii2 Advance application.

Now I want to configure [adminLTE](http://almsaeedstudio.com/AdminLTE/) theme in my Yii2 Advance application without using the Composer. Somehow Composer is not getting installed on my machine.

Ref: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/729/tutorial-about-how-to-integrate-yii2-with-fantastic-theme-adminlte/

Comment: you need to create AssetBundle for your theme

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1) Go to https://github.com/almasaeed2010/AdminLTE/releases and download last version.

2) Create folder `bower` in `vendor` path. And in `bower` create new folder `admin-lte` again.

3) Extract archive from first step to `/vendor/bower/admin-lte`.

4) Change your `AppAsset` (it is location in `backend/assets` folder) and add this code:

```
class AppAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $sourcePath = '@bower/';
    public $css = ['admin-lte/dist/css/AdminLTE.css'];
    public $js = ['admin-lte/dist/js/AdminLTE/app.js'];
    public $depends = [
        'yii\web\YiiAsset',
        'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',
        'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapPluginAsset',
    ];
}
```

Comment: The easier way  is  to  install adminLTE  with 

"bower install adminlte"

You need to  replace  "admin-lte/dist"  with "adminlte/dist" then.

Comment: Follow this Youtube video for help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AUbMpjDauq0

Comment: Is it possible to add the admin-lte theme in yii2-basic ????

Comment: Yes, change folder `backend/assets` to `assets` and change `AppAsset`

Answer (score 0):

Embeding admin lte theme i yii2 basic

1) create yii project using composer

sudo du
cd /var/www/html
composer create-project yiisoft/yii2-app-basic basic 2.0.4

2)now create it accessible

chmod 777 -R project name

3) download admin lte theme by using

git clone https://github.com/bmsrox/baseapp-yii2basic-adminlte.git

copy and past all file to your basic root folder

4) now update composer

composer update

if token error then  create account in git and create token in setting tab by clicking genarate new token

copy and provide it to composer

5) update your web.php file in config

```
<?php

$params = require(__DIR__ . '/params.php');

$config = [
    'id' => 'basic',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    'bootstrap' => ['log'],
    'layout'=>'column2',
    'layoutPath'=>'@app/themes/adminLTE/layouts',
    'components' => [

     'urlManager' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules' => [
                ''=>'site/index',
                '<action:(index|login|logout)>'=>'site/<action>',
                '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>'
            ],
        ],

         'view' => [
            'theme' => [
                'pathMap' => ['@app/views' => '@app/themes/adminLTE'],
                'baseUrl' => '@web/../themes/adminLTE',
            ],
        ],

        'request' => [
            // !!! insert a secret key in the following (if it is empty) - this is required by cookie validation
            'cookieValidationKey' => 'n0VkMX1RmIa_ovJmwR3Gn_hdZyQ7SyKe',
        ],
        'cache' => [
            'class' => 'yii\caching\FileCache',
        ],
        'user' => [
            'identityClass' => 'app\models\User',
            'enableAutoLogin' => true,
        ],
        'errorHandler' => [
            'errorAction' => 'site/error',
        ],
        'mailer' => [
            'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
            // send all mails to a file by default. You have to set
            // 'useFileTransport' to false and configure a transport
            // for the mailer to send real emails.
            'useFileTransport' => true,
        ],
        'log' => [
            'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
            'targets' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                    'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'db' => require(__DIR__ . '/db.php'),
    ],
    'params' => $params,
];

if (YII_ENV_DEV) {
    // configuration adjustments for 'dev' environment
    $config['bootstrap'][] = 'debug';
    $config['modules']['debug'] = 'yii\debug\Module';

    $config['bootstrap'][] = 'gii';
    //$config['modules']['gii'] = 'yii\gii\Module';
    $config['modules']['gii'] = [
            'class' => 'yii\gii\Module',
            'generators' => [ //here
                'crud' => [ // generator name
                    'class' => 'yii\gii\generators\crud\Generator', // generator class
                    'templates' => [ //setting for out templates
                        'custom' => '@vendor/bmsrox/yii-adminlte-crud-template', // template name => path to template
                    ]
                ]
            ],
        ];
}

return $config;
```

6) update SiteController. Php in controller folder

replace actionLogout with following code

```
public function actionLogout()
    {
        Yii::$app->user->logout();

        return $this->redirect(Yii::$app->user->loginUrl);
    }

    public function beforeAction($action)
    {
        if (parent::beforeAction($action)) {
            // change layout for error action
            if ($action->id=='login')
                 $this->layout = 'login';
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

7) if misconfiguration error then

update apche2

by using command

a2enmod rewrite

and restrart apache using

service apache2 restart

finished...........

best of luck

Comment: Question has asked for Yii2 Advance application not basic template.